# Getting variables from an outer class

Tags: python

I'm doing a project in Python which requires me to make a nested class. I need to get a variable from the class it is nested in but haven't been able to. I want to be able to get the self variables from Parent in the Child class but my code isn't working, is there any way I could inherit the Parent class' variables? Here is what I tried:

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 1;
    self.y = 2;
  
  class Child:
    
    def __init__(self):
      pass;

    def parent_vars(self):
      att = super()["x"];
      print(att);

parent = Parent();
child = parent.Child();

child.parent_vars();
```

Comment: Child is nested in Parent, but that's **not** the same thing as inheriting from it. You can't use super to access the outer class attributes. There's no guarantee when Parent.Child is instantiated that Parent ever has been, and certainly no connection between those instances.

Comment: The only projects that *require* nested classes are poorly designed homework assignments written by teachers who think Java is the pinnacle of language design.

Comment: Ranting aside, what is the *purpose* of the assignment? `Child` is just another attribute of `Parent`; it doesn't know anything about a particular *instance* of `Parent`.

Comment: You can define one class inside another, not because it fills some semantic void, but because there's no reason to *disallow* it.

Comment: Possible solution is to create a method of "Parent" which creates and returns a "Child" object and gives this child a reference to the parent (e. g. by a constructor for "Child" which takes parent's reference).

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's a solution in search of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, unlike in Java, a class serves more as a namespace than as an object. An inner class (in this case `Parent.Child`) is no different semantically than the same class defined as a standalone - the outer class is simply how it's accessed (and it's accessed statically, not requiring an instance - again unlike Java).

If you want a `Child` to take its `Parent`'s variables, you'll need to tell the `Child` explicitly which object is its `Parent`:

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 1
    self.y = 2

  class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent):
      self.parent = parent

    def parent_vars(self):
      att = self.parent.x
      print(att)

par = Parent()
child = Parent.Child(par)  # note how `Parent.Child`, not `par.Child()`
child.parent_vars()
# 1
```